# What options are available for hunting feral boar on Hawaii?

Tags: local-customs, activities, hawaii, hunting

I am visiting Kauai shortly and am interested in boar hunting while there. So far I have applied for my [Hunter's Education Exemption](https://hunting.ehawaii.gov/hunting/hunting_req.html) and have mapped several locations that allow for bow hunting.

While researching, I came across a [blog post](http://guysareallthesame.blogspot.com/2010/08/dream-come-true-wild-boar-hunt-with-dog.html) that mentioned the writer simply asked an employee of the hotel he was staying at and was put in touch with a group who invited him to go with them. Is something like this a common occurrence? I do not wish to hunt alone as I am unfamiliar with the territory, but I also do not wish to spend a great deal of money on the hunting "tours" that are provided by local businesses.

Also, I have had little luck finding a place to process the animal should I be successful while hunting on the island. I would prefer to have the animal processed there as it will cut down on the cost of shipping back to my home state. Does anyone have any experience with game processing on the island of Kauai?

Are there any other cultural/logistic considerations I should be aware of? Thanks!

Comment: See also [Outdoors.SE].

Comment: @gerrit Thanks! I didn't know about that site. Is my question still appropriate for here or should I move it?

Comment: Dryden, I'd consider it's on-topic on both in this case.  I've had a minority viewpoint in the past, where I take a narrower interpretation of travel than others (I don't think *any* activity performed while travelling is necessarily on-topic).  So I've stopped flagging for moving and I rather try to advertise [Outdoors.SE] (which needs more questions) at any relevant question.

Comment: @DrydenLong are you only after Kauai or would other islands suffice?

Comment: @MarkMayo Only Kauai this trip. If you have info on other islands though, I'd love to hear it since I'm sure I'll visit them in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I initially asked in a comment whether you were specifically asking, then realised it didn't matter.  I'd found a [New York Times article about hunting in Hawaii, but specifically on Oahu](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/05/19/travel/hunting-pesky-pigs-in-hawaii.html).

However, the hunter guide that they mention, [Hook You Up Outfitters](http://hookyouupoutfitters.com/), has a page on [hunting hogs](http://www.hookyouupoutfitters.com/hunting.htm) (about half way down) and they indeed include hunting options on Oahu, the Big Island, and Kauai, so it looks like they may be a viable option for you on this and future  trips.

Comment: Thanks. I looked into Hook You Up and they seemed like a good way to go, but a little more than I'd be willing to spend. Don't get me wrong, they're right on par with any guide service, but I was hoping to get away with spending less. +1 for the good article and the solid post though!

Comment: @DrydenLong I guess you could contact them and ask if there are lower-cost companies that they could recommend - say something along the lines of how great they look and you'd consider them on your next trip, but you want something a bit more light-weight this time around.